# Searches for "more information about text formats"

Tags: drupal, seo, robots.txt, spam-prevention

I have a site using Drupal as CMS, and got "infected" badly with spammer bots.

Moreover, recently I signed up for Google's Webmaster Tools, and I see that one of the top search queries that result in my site is "`more information about text formats`"
And I know that this block of text appears in drupal sites.

So I'm guessing that this is the bots' way to find spammable drupal sites. So is there a precaution for this? I already made robots.txt to `Disallow: /drupal-subfolder/` but apparently this does not affect malicious bots.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare a list of bots which you don't want to allow on your website & mention them in robots.txt like

```
User-agent: <bot_identifier>
Disallow: /
```

[Here](http://www.tareeinternet.com/forum/knowledgebase/235-blocking-bad-bots-robots-txt.html) is a exhaustive bad bots list.

But still many bad bots will not respect it & crawl your site. For that you need to install application like [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to restrict the crawlers which are crawling at a higher rate.